# Missing sidebar parameter "fix" - before_content

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar, css, html

as you know the sidebar parameters from [register_sidebar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) that control the widget layout are

```
- before_widget
- after_widget
- before_title
- after_title
```

the problem is that you cannot implement certain type of designs because a parameter like '`before_content`' is missing.

for example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    title  
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

a HTML structure like this is only possible if you add  `<div class="content">` in the `after_title` parameter. The problem is that if you do this, widgets without titles will break the page layout :(

so is there a solution to somehow add that `<div class="content">` after `div.title`, or after `div.container` if title is missing?

Comment: I re-update all of this to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385954/do-wordpress-widget-or-sidebar-hooks-exist

Comment: before_title and after_title is somehow deprecated in wordpress now. Probably it's best to not rely on them at all for your site's design an encapsulate the whole widget instead. With which widget are you running into trouble?

Comment: Deprecated? You sure about that hakre?

Comment: Wait: what? Deprecated? Please, say it ain't so. I don't want to be forced to use H2 heading tags for Widget titles, as they do not conform to my Theme's markup semantics.

Answer (score 2):

This code detects whether a title has been set, and if not, it changes the `before_widget` argument.

```
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'wpse4213_widget_display_callback', 10, 3 );
function wpse4213_widget_display_callback( $instance, $widget, $args )
{
    if ( empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        $args['before_widget'] = '<div class="container"><div class="content">';
        $widget->widget( $args, $instance );
        return false;
    }
    return $instance;
}
```

This code works because the `widget_display_callback` allows you to return `false` if you don't want to display the widget. In this case we display the widget ourselves, so we don't want WordPress to do it again. A hack, but it works.

This function will fail if the widget supplies a default title (like most widgets bundled in the core distribution do). To detect this, I also created a function that first tries to render the widget in an output buffer. If we detect a title element in this output buffer the widget did have a default title - so we ignore the buffer and display it like a regular widget. But this can also break when the widget uses overactive caching, so we must try to flush that too. Did I mention this is a hack?

```
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'wpse4213_widget_display_callback', 10, 3 );
function wpse4213_widget_display_callback( $instance, $widget, $args )
{
    if ( empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        $args['before_widget'] = '<div class="container"><div class="content">';
        ob_start();
        $widget->widget( $args, $instance );
        $widget_content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        if ( false !== strpos( $widget_content, 'widget-title' ) ) {
            // It did return a title!
            if ( method_exists( $widget, 'flush_widget_cache' ) ) {
                $widget->flush_widget_cache();
            }
            return $instance;
        }
        echo $widget_content;
        return false;
    }
    return $instance;
}
```